# Call for research

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I want to explain that we have brought up new research questions and invite researchers to solve them. Do the following sentences make sense for a native? If yes, Which one is better? If no, what replacement can I use? (My sense is that the third one is somewhat rude, isn't  it?)

- We bring up new research questions around the paradigm and **call for new research to** investigate it and provide solutions for implementing it.
- We bring up new research questions around the paradigm and **call for researchers to** investigate it and provide solutions for implementing it.
- We bring up new research questions around the paradigm and **call researchers to** investigate it and provide solutions for implementing it.

Comment: For starters, we don't say: bring up new research. And it's: call ***on**** researchers to investigate them...etc. I think you mean: We point out  research issues regarding this paradigm and call on researchers to investigate them and provide solutions for implementing them.

Comment: The free dictionary mentions: "call on somebody: 1. to ask someone to do something."" Doesn't that convey some kind of ordering someone and isn't it considered rude? Consider that some researchers are reading or reviewing a paper and the author calls on them to do something. Isn't it considered rude?

Comment: @Shayan Not necessarily considered rude. However, I disagree with Lambie: you can use either *call for* or *call on* in the second sentence in my opinion. Furthermore, we do indeed say *bring up new research questions.* We bring up questions all the time. I would not use the last sentence, unless you were actually physically calling or phoning researchers. Finally, there's a sense of *call for* that means requires: *Our new questions call for researchers to investigate them.* In this case, it is the questions themselves that require, or call for, research.